# webdriver: disable "would you like to make IE your default browser" message

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, testng

My default browser is FF but i run my scripts on other browsers as well
So, when i start for example IE, it asks "would you like to make IE your default browser" !
Is it possible to turn off this message in some way? 
I'm using webdriver + testNG + java!
It's not a big issue but i'd like to have my screen clean :-)

Comment: Yes, once you set that up manually. Then it will not ask you again during your automation. It makes a lot of sense to set it up manually rather trying to write a bunch of code for that.

Answer (score 2):

Open **Internet Options**.  On **Programs** tab, uncheck "**Tell me if Internet Explorer is not the default browser.**" Worked for me on IE 9 and 11.

Can also be disabled by a Windows policy: "Disable changing default browser check"